# profiling drupal with xdebug in windows, but no profile file

Tags: php, windows, drupal, profiling, xdebug

I'm trying to profile for the first time with Xdebug in Windows, but no profile files are being generated.  I've seen several answers here on Stack Overflow and elsewhere for similar questions, tried them all, but to no avail.

My setup is Windows 8.1, PHP 5.4 using a WAMP stack. Xdebug is enabled and works fine. It's just the profiling part which I can't seem to get to work.

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
;xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=1
xdebug.profiler_append=1
xdebug.profiler_output_name="cachegrind.out.%H-%R-%s"
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="C:/Users/Badlapje/profiler"
xdebug.remote_log="C:/wamp/logs"
```

I've of course tried it by using the `xdebug.profiler_enable` rather then `enable_trigger`, but neither method created a `cachegrind.out` file.

Comment: you can use xhprof http://php.net/manual/en/book.xhprof.php

Comment: Does the directory `C:/Users/Badlapje/profiler` exist and is writable by the PHP?